# Upload php script in Aptana

Tags: php, aptana

I've started using Aptana studio recently and I was wondering how to upload a php file locally in Aptana Studio 3.I've worked with dreamweaver cs5 which provides an upload button.

Comment: I stopped using aptana partly because of the lack of ftp possibilities (although a while ago...) and switched to NetBeans ( http://netbeans.org/ ). In NetBeans you can add multiple sites to ftp to just like in Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but your best bet is to use an external FTP program, FTP in Eclipse/Aptana is really frustrating.

Comment: can you tell me about any ftp program you're familiar with ?

Comment: I've heard that [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) is good. I personally use [transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) as I like the synchronise feature (not sure if cyberduck has that)

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a bit tricky, but noy as @ianbarker says. Follow these steps :

step 1 : Create new web project -> name it -> select location -> finish;

step 2 : in the left view of aptana you should have 2 tabs; select app explorer, then from the dropdown list select your project;

step 3 : a little bit higher than the dropdown list, you should have a set of four buttons. Click on the second(it should be named publish); than click on "Run Web Deployment Wizard..."

step 4 : from the window that just opened, select fpt/sftp/ftps -> click next

step 5 : a new window will open. You will have to complete the fields like this :

Site Name : The way you want to name your connection

Server : `ftp.yourdomain.com` or simply `domain.com`, or the ip address of the server you ar trying to connect to.

Username/Password : the username provided by you hosting holder. Check "Save";

Remote Path : click browse; select the folder on the ftp in which your site is located;

Connect Mode : Passive;

Encoding : Whatever you need

Timezone : click "Detect"

Check Automaticaly...blah blah blah and then check "... both directions"

Finish;

step 6 : if you click again on "Publish" button you will see a little more options. I usualy go with "Transfer files". Click it. In your editor window will apear two small windows. The one on your left contains files stored on local machine, and the one in your right is the server. In the middle you have three buttons : "Upload" - uploads all the files from the local machine to the server; pay attention, it overwrites existing files . "Donwload" - quite the oposite of "Upload". Synchronize - compares files on both local an server and provides the best option for the update of files on local and server machine. If you want synch to work properly, it is necesarily that you click "Detect" in the timezone field, because aptana also compares by "Date Updated" headers of the files